# Windows software to show key-presses on screen

Tags: windows, keyboard

I would like to know what software is available for showing key presses on the screen.

I have an online presentation. I would like for the viewers to be able to check the keys I am pressing on my keyboard. A utility similar to Screenkey for Ubuntu would be nice

I have seen this `NohBoard` [https://github.com/ThoNohT/NohBoard/releases] but I have to put the whole keyboard (or some parts). This is inconvenient for me as, at most I will do 3-4 key presses in a row, .e.g, <kbd>ctl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd>.

I would like one software that has a couple of boxes in a corner of the screen for this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It would help to know why. My reason is that the keyboard does not have a status for shift lock.

Comment: I have an online presentation. I would like for the viewers to be able to check the key's I am pressing on my keyboard. An utility similar to `Screenkey`  for `Ubuntu` would be nice

Comment: I think that helps a lot in others trying to answer it.  But it's best if you edit your question to add details to it as comments can disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some softwares to show key-presses on screen available for windows.

### [KeyPress OSD](https://github.com/marius-sucan/KeyPress-OSD)

- Support for at least 110 keyboard layouts covering about 55
  languages. It recognizes keys with Shift, AltGr and dead keys for
  each of these layouts
- Automatic detection of keyboard layouts
- Typed text history with Page Up/Down. On pressing Enter or Escape, it
  records the written line and you can get back to it with Page Up
- Automatic resizing of OSD/HUD or fixed size
- Customizable size, position and colors
- The OSD can hide or switch position automatically when the mouse runs
  over it
- Customizable visual mouse clicks and mouse halo to indicate its
  location, and flash mouse cursor after idling
- Multi-monitor support
- Portable. No need to install/uninstall. Settings stored in an easy to
  read INI file
- Easy to configure with many options in Settings windows to toggle
  features and customize behavior and look

---

### [Carnac](https://github.com/Code52/carnac)

- A utility to give some insight into how you use your keyboard
- It has the highest number of Stargazers on GitHub in this list.  3.4k
  stars

---

### [YAKD - Yet Another Key Displayer](https://github.com/Jagailo/YetAnotherKeyDisplayer)

- Capture keyboard and mouse
- 2 displaying modes are available: display keys in a window or send
  them to RTSS for display in fullscreen games
- Ability to change the keys font, size, color and background
- Auto-save of all styles settings
- Key Displayer as a window can be captured in OBS (use the chroma key
  filter to make the window transparent)

---

### [KeyCastOW](https://github.com/brookhong/KeyCastOW)

- small footprint (one 100kb executable file)
- green and portable, only depends on windows system dlls
- plenty of settings for keystroke display
- hotkey to turn on/off

---

### [Kling](https://github.com/KaustubhPatange/Kling)

- Visually display keys on Windows screen
- Detect multiple keys and key holds
- Allow you to change location of display
- Allow you to change amount of display time

Comment: All of these will work on windows

Comment: KeyPress OSD  seems a good option. It is available on the microsoft store and has a 5-day trial

Comment: There is also a free version of keypress OSD available [here](https://github.com/marius-sucan/KeyPress-OSD) but it won't be the latest version and is less optimized.

Comment: Carnac, YAKD, KeyCastOW and Kling are also great options worth checking out.

Comment: Try all of them and choose the one that suits your needs the best.

Comment: which one did you choose?

Comment: So far none. But I will most likely go with the trial version `KeyPress OSD` since it is available on the microsoft store. That way, I will not have to install programs from outside sources

Answer (score 0):

KeyPress OSD is a great app. Sadly, there doesn't appear to be any way (or option) to simply restart a display entry; it always appends a previous entry. It can only be cleared manually (via an assigned key)...which is less than ideal.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).